# finding a User object in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

Ruby on rails noob here.

User fields relevant to this question: id (prim. key). Post fields relevant to this question: id, user_id (fk). The foreign key is user_id of Posts which is connected to id of Users. Is the following the right syntax? I want to grab the User object who posted the current post:
(this is in controllers/posts_controller.rb)

```
@id = Post.find(params[:id]).user_id 
@user = User.find(@id)
```

You can see the context of the code below:

```
def sendMessage
  #@user = current_user
  @id = Post.find(params[:id]).user_id 
  @user = User.find(@id)
  UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
  respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :nothing => true, :status => :ok }
  end
end
```

The reason I'm asking is because an email is not getting sent to the user who created the post. Now, I know that this isn't an email issue because, as a test, I tried commenting out the two lines in question and simply using:

```
@user = current_user
```

...and this sends an email to the user who's logged in (but this isn't what I want).

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Comment: Yes that looks ok, why you don't try it first and post it if you get an error?

Comment: hi timaschew, i've edited my post to clear things up.

Comment: for testing try to render the user(id) with `render_text(@user)`

Answer (score 3):

You should have your models set up as follows:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :posts

end
```

Then in your controller you can do:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
@user = @post.user
```

Comment: thx Ant. i do already have the above code in the models. i've also edited my post to make it a little bit more clear. i tried your controller code (thx) but there's still no email being sent.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the proper relations in the model.

I guess 'has_many :posts' in User and 'belongs_to :user' in Post.

Then you'll be able to do:

```
@user = Post.find(params[:id]).user
```